# Visual Studio Time Out

Tags: visual-studio

When I debug my program, which consists of looping over thousands of entries in vectors multiple times, it simply freezes the program but does not provide any error messages whatsoever. Does Visual Studio have some sort of auto-time out that I am experiencing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check may be your program is going into infinite loop Or doing some heavy task that makes your UI unresponsive(if you have windows form). Since you are debugging this program then why dont you set breakpoint in code and check where your program is causing issue.

And yes there is no time out for Visual Studio,But for program window.This is known as Hang Status.
   When an application (or more accurately, a thread) creates a window on the desktop, it enters into an implicit contract with the Desktop Window Manager (DWM) to process window messages in a timely fashion. The DWM posts messages (keyboard/mouse input and messages from other windows, as well as itself) into the thread-specific message queue. The thread retrieves and dispatches those messages via its message queue. If the thread does not service the queue by calling GetMessage(), messages are not processed, and the window hangs: it can neither redraw nor can it accept input from the user. The operating system detects this state by attaching a timer to pending messages in the message queue. If a message has not been retrieved within 5 seconds, the DWM declares the window to be hung. You can query this particular window state via the IsHungAppWindow() API.

Detection is only the first step. At this point, the user still cannot even terminate the application - clicking the X (Close) button would result in a WM_CLOSE message, which would be stuck in the message queue just like any other message. The Desktop Window Manager assists by seamlessly hiding and then replacing the hung window with a 'ghost' copy displaying a bitmap of the original window's previous client area (and adding "Not Responding" to the title bar). As long as the original window's thread does not retrieve messages, the DWM manages both windows simultaneously, but allows the user to interact only with the ghost copy. Using this ghost window, the user can only move, minimize, and - most importantly - close the unresponsive application, but not change its internal state.

A nice article is written in this following link.
[How program window works](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd744765(v=vs.85).aspx)